# How to remove submodule from .gitmodules

Tags: git

> I have one requirement How to remove submodule from .gitmodules file
>   using command ?

Can anybody assist on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a submodule?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-submodule)

Answer (score 1):

There is no command to do that, you need to do it manually, as the [tutorial](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSubmoduleTutorial#Removal) suggests:

> To remove a submodule you need to:
>
> 1. Delete the relevant line from the .gitmodules file.
> 2. Delete the relevant section from .git/config.
> 3. Run git rm --cached path_to_submodule (no trailing slash).
> 4. Commit the superproject.
> 5. Delete the now untracked submodule files.

However, you could also just issue `git submodule deinit` on the submodule - but it doesn't remove it from .gitmodules.